# How do I create a grouped exposed filter on a block?

Tags: views, 8

I have both a "Galery" content type and a "Galery category" taxonomy. The taxonomy only has two terms, 'Video' and 'Photo' (picture).

When I create a Galery content type, I need to choose the galery category.

I created a view that would display an exposed form, that would allow the user to either pick one of the 2 available categories. A colleague helped me setting up a grouped search and customizing it. Here is how it looks:

[image: filte]

However, when testing it, we realized nothing was displayed. Moreover, the `<Any>` choice does display everything, so I think I've wrongly set something.

If this helps, I'm using "better exposed form" with the "autosubmit" and "use ajax" functions enabled.

What is happening and how should I fix it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without trying to recreate your grouped search, I think it might be a logic error where your search will show all the results for Label `<Photo>` is one of "Photo" taxonomy term AND Label `<Video>` is one of "Video" taxonomy term.

What happens if you combine both of them into one item, where Label `<Type>` is one of "Photo" OR "Video" taxonomy terms? (If necessary, you can allow users to search both terms at once by allowing multiple selections on the single exposed taxonomy filter.)

Comment: I had to dig a little but I made it work, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your view, make sure your exposed filter is not the gallery type field itself, but 'Has taxonomy term' filter with the taxonomy group vocabulary selected and then set the exposed grouped filters the same way.